# kubuntu 14.10, screen goes blank during HDD icon loading

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 14.10

I am in a pickle with this relatively new installation of Kubuntu 14.10.
Not knowing where to start, I will go from the beginning.

I installed the system a few days ago. Everything installed fine and worked almost perfectly. Almost because for some reasons, after the system booted, the writing was so small that I could not understand them, even after changing the resolution to the lowest possible. 
After a reboot, everything went to normal.

For a few days the system worked magnificently, until today, after leaving the PC on at lunch, the system froze and I had to hard reboot. Since then, the screen goes black every time that the HDD icon appears on the screen (hence loading the 1920x1080 resolution).

I tried to boot in recover mode and remove the NVidia drivers, then resume the boot. The system boots normally at a lower resolution. As soon as I restart the system, the PC goes back to HD, and the same issue happens (screen shuts off during HDD icon).

The driver in use is the native NOUVEAU. If I try to re-install (via GUI) the Nvidia driver, the same problem stays.

This situation happened in this same PC a couple of months ago when I tried the same installation.

I did install Kubuntu 14.10 on other 2 PC (one with Nvidia 7800GT graphic card) and there it works normally.

This system graphic card is a GT610 Nvidia and I am using the HDMI as output.

What baffles me is that it worked for a few days, then it stopped.

Any idea?

Edit #1 - I did extensive research on different sites, but I haven't found a working solution for this problem. Most of the problems I read, tell that the screen doesn't even appear, but stays black and the couple of similar posts I found do not show a solution for this issue, but for the issue already mentioned where the screen is black from the beginning. It is not a matter of brightness, since the monitor is actually off.

I tend to agree that is an issue of graphic card, but I still don't understand why the screen in high resolution starts, then it blacks out after a few seconds. Also I don't understand why it was working for a few days, then it stopped.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the solution:

Enter the directory `~/.kde/share/apps/kscreen` List files and there will be listed two files which were made prior to this problem... In my case, I renamed 2 files with long weird names, lost some settings like keyboard shortcuts for Screen Lock & Show Desktop. Maybe I lost something else but I'm happy after 2 days of thinking something is wrong with video driver.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. It would probably help the OP if you clarify which files were deleted, and detail whether the shortcuts that disappeared were pre-existing, or modifications you made. Any extra detail will improve this answer, and bag you some upvotes :)

Comment: it was these two files:

file named: c21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682, with this content: [ { "enabled" : true, "id" : "default", "metadata" : { "name" : "default" }, "mode" : { "refresh" : 73.0, "size" : { "height" : 480, "width" : 640 } }, "pos" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 0 }, "primary" : true, "rotation" : 1 } ]

and file named 7e9cfa2029b51b820362948b49a1c3ca, with this content: [ { "enabled" : false, "id" : "dbbd5ab8bb0e4368d510c1b92849d3c9", "metadata" : { "fullname" : "xrandr-PHL 243V5-ZV0143300140", "name" : "VGA-0" }, "pos" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 18 }, "primary" : true, "rotation" : 1 } ]

Comment: Cool, it'd be better to edit it into the answer, click the grey edit on the left hand side of your answer, and copy/paste it. You'll get a badge for your first edit too!